# how to unhide the ScrollView after converting it PDF in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, uiscrollview

I am creating pdf from UIScrollView.

It works fine and creates a PDF but the problem is that after creation of pdf the scrollView is vanished from the screen and when i again load the app then it again shows,so i think due to pdf creation it hides any way to unhide it after creating PDF.

I am using following code:

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView: (UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName: (NSString*)aFilename
{
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    CGRect scrollSize = CGRectMake(1018,76,1010,1600);

    [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(1018,76,1010,1600)];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData,scrollView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, problem is in below line

```
[scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(1018,76,1010,1600)];
```

This will make the scrollview out of visible area because your Origin X is 1018. So, actually it is not hidden but it is out of screen or visible area.

Do you really need that line.

Comment: so may add this line after calling method of createPDF

Comment: but why are you setting such a odd frame? any special needs

Comment: it is from interface builder value and in landscape mode